# Передача файла на сервер CURL

Tags: php, curl, файлы

Пытаюсь передать файл на сервер, использую CURL

Запрос формируется так:

```
$postdata = array(
            'FileToLoad' => "@".$this->file."; filename=\"$this->filename\";",
            'fileId' => $this->fileId);
```

`$this->file` содержит полный путь до файла на сервере `/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/tmp/file.pdf`

Отправляю так:

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ".ASPXAUTH=$this->token;");
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
        }
```

Запрос проходит успешно, но данные попадают в $_POST, а я их очень хочу увидеть в $_FILES. Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Какая версия PHP? Загрузка файлов синтаксисом @ объявлена устаревшей в PHP5.5 и отключена по-умолчанию в 5.6. Вместо этого синтаксиса надо использовать класс CURLFile. И зачем вы пытаетесь сбросить CURLOPT_ENCODING?

Comment: @Мелкий, версия 5.6. Буду признателен за рабочую ссылку на класс. CURLOPT_ENCODING используется для разбора ответа от сервера, который сжимает ответ в gzip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как выяснили в комментариях, речь о PHP 5.6. Начиная с этой версии загрузка файлов синтаксисом через @ отключена по-умолчанию. Теперь файлы нужно загружать через класс [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php), как-то так:

```
$postdata = array(
        'FileToLoad' => new CURLFile($this->file, null /*или mime-type*/, $this->filename),
        'fileId' => $this->fileId,
);
```

Код самого запроса остаётся тем же самым.

Как видно, исправляется несложно. Но для полноты ответа добавлю, что для старого кода включить обратно передачу файлов через синтаксис @ пока возможно опцией `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD`

Answer (score 2):

Для поддержки старых версий PHP

```
if (!function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
    function curl_file_create($filename, $mimetype = '', $postname = '') {
        if(file_exists($filename))
            return "@$filename;filename="
            . ($postname ?: basename($filename))
            . ($mimetype ? ";type=$mimetype" : '');
        else
            exit('Error! File '.$filename.' not found!');
    }
}
```

И вызывать:

```
curl_file_create($file)
```